# Prometheus Alert Rule for Absent Discovered Target

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I got an alert while configuring the monitoring module using `prometheus/kube-prometheus-stack 25.1.0`.

**Alert**

```
[FIRING:1] KubeProxyDown - critical
Alert: Target disappeared from Prometheus target discovery. - critical
 Description: KubeProxy has disappeared from Prometheus target discovery.
 Details:
  • alertname: KubeProxyDown
  • prometheus: monitoring/prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus
  • severity: critical
```

I think it is a new default rule in `kube-prometheus-stack 25.x.x`. It does not exist in `prometheus/kube-prometheus-stack 21.x.x`.

The same issue happened in the EKS and minikube.

**KubeProxyDown** Rule

```
alert: KubeProxyDown
expr: absent(up{job="kube-proxy"}
  == 1)
for: 15m
labels:
  severity: critical
annotations:
  description: KubeProxy has disappeared from Prometheus target discovery.
  runbook_url: https://runbooks.prometheus-operator.dev/runbooks/kubernetes/kubeproxydown
  summary: Target disappeared from Prometheus target discovery.
```

How can I resolve this issue?

I would be thankful if anyone could help me

Comment: I don't understand the issue. Is it that the rule was changed between 25 and 21?

Comment: What kubernetes version are you using? Did you check if your `kube-proxy` operator is running? There is a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60734799/all-kubernetes-proxy-targets-down-prometheus-operator)

Comment: Same problem here, running a k3s cluster. Alarm first appeared after upgrading prometheus-stack to version 25.x.x

Comment: > What kubernetes version are you using? 

1.19

> Did you check if your kube-proxy operator is running?
 
Yes, kube-proxy operator is running

Answer (score 5):

There was a change in `metrics-bind-address` in `kube-proxy`. Following the issues posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60734799/all-kubernetes-proxy-targets-down-prometheus-operator), [here](https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/16476) and [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/74300). I can suggest the following.  Change `kube-proxy` ConfigMap to different value:

```
$ kubectl edit cm/kube-proxy -n kube-system
## Change from
    metricsBindAddress: 127.0.0.1:10249 ### <--- Too secure
## Change to
    metricsBindAddress: 0.0.0.0:10249
$ kubectl delete pod -l k8s-app=kube-proxy -n kube-system
```

Comment: As @demisx mentioned, in his answer to this ticket, it seems to be a typo in this answer: the configmap is not called `kube-proxy` but `kube-proxy-config`. There you can find the `metricsBindAddress` property mentioned here.

Answer (score 5):

This is what worked for me in AWS EKS cluster v1.21:

```
$ kubectl edit cm/kube-proxy-config -n kube-system
---
metricsBindAddress: 127.0.0.1:10249 ### <--- change to 0.0.0.0:10249
$ kubectl delete pod -l k8s-app=kube-proxy -n kube-system
```

Note, the name of the config map is `kube-proxy-config`, not `kube-proxy`

Answer (score 0):

Both previous answers are correct, but if you are upgrading to eks 1.22, you could only upgrade the kube-proxy addon to v1.22.11-eksbuild.2 (current one)
and the cm will be automatically updated

`metricsBindAddress: 127.0.0.1:10249`

to

`metricsBindAddress: 0.0.0.0:10249`

without the need to update it manually

You can see AWS kube-proxy addon documentation from
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/managing-kube-proxy.html